# Storyboard Automatically Adjust Font/AutoShrink does not work with dynamic UILabelHeight

Tags: swift, uilabel

This appears to be a bug in XCode, but I'm interested to see if I did something wrong.

To Reproduce error:

- I have a UIImage set to 1:1 ratio.
- I have a label to the same width as the image, and the label height is set to 1/6 the image height. The label is below the image.
- I also set other autolayout hugging to the edges.

I set, in XCode Automatically Adjust Font on, and AutoShrink to Minimum Font Scale = 0.25.

Yet, the font does not shrink and appears like this:

[image]

Please advise why the font does not shrink and how I can shrink it.

Comment: You have to add a label with an image using equal width and aspect ratio and you want that label is resizable, right?

Comment: Correct. I want the font to change

Comment: You don't need to set a minimum auto scale for label

Comment: My question is why it doesn't work.

Comment: You set a fix height for the label

Comment: Did not set a fixed height for the label it should adjust the size of the font.